# Recursively getting all nested elements from a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I am a python newbie, just implemented my first ID3 in python and have my rules in dict form like this

```
{'a' : {'b': 'no', 'c': 'no', 'd': {'z': {'q': 'no', 'y': 'yes'}}}}
```

I now want to output this as

```
<a = b >---> 'no'
<a = c >---> 'no'
<a = d > AND <z = q >---> 'no'
<a = d > AND <z = y >---> 'yes'
```

I just cant seem to get it right

Here is my code:
Supposed to return everything as a single string separated by commas

```
def printer(a):
    keys = a.keys()
    for i in keys:
        rules = ""
        for j in a[i].keys():
            tulip = "< Attribute " + str(i) + " = "
            tulip += str(j)
            tulip += " > "
            if type(a[i][j]) == str:
                tulip += "--->" + str(a[i][j]) 
                rules += tulip
                rules += ","
            else:
                tulip += "AND " 
                tulip += str(printer(a[i][j]))
            rules += tulip    

    return rules
```

Comment: Can you post your code, difficult to tell you what's wrong without your code

Comment: A nested dict is essentially a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29). Use any applicable tree algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ***Updated:***

For a recursive function that prints these rules with arbitrary nesting, you can use the following:

**Updated Dict and Function**

```
rules = {4: {'s': 'No', 'a': 'e', 'p': 'No', 'c': 'No', 'l': 'e', 'f': 'No', 'm': 'No', 'n': {19: {'o': 'e', 'r': 'No', 'b': 'e', 'h': 'e', 'w': {21: {'p': 'e', 'w': 'e', 'd': {1: {'s': 'e', 'f': 'No', 'y': 'No'}}, 'g': 'e', 'l': {2: {'c': 'e', 'w': 'No', 'n': 'e', 'y': 'No'}}}}, 'k': 'e', 'n': 'e', 'y': 'e'}}, 'y': 'No'}}
string_rules = [] # to keep them in a list


def print_nested_count(myDict, parent=None, out=[], count=0):
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            count += 1  # signifies recursion level
            if parent and count % 2 == 0:
                out.append("<{} = {}> AND ".format(parent, key))
            count = print_nested_count(value, key, out, count=count)
        else:
            if count:
                string_rules.append("".join(out).lstrip() + "<{} = {}> ----> {}".format(parent, key, value))
    if count % 2 == 0 and out:
        out.pop()
    count -= 1
    return count
```

**Updated Output**:

By calling this function and printing each line in `string_rules`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_nested_count(rules)
    for line in string_rules: print(line)
```

Input format:

```
{4: {'a': 'e',
     'c': 'No',
     'f': 'No',
     'l': 'e',
     'm': 'No',
     'n': {19: {'b': 'e',
                'h': 'e',
                'k': 'e',
                'n': 'e',
                'o': 'e',
                'r': 'No',
                'w': {21: {'d': {1: {'f': 'No', 's': 'e', 'y': 'No'}},
                           'g': 'e',
                           'l': {2: {'c': 'e', 'n': 'e', 'w': 'No', 'y': 'No'}},
                           'p': 'e',
                           'w': 'e'}},
                'y': 'e'}},
     'p': 'No',
     's': 'No',
     'y': 'No'}}
```

Output format:

```
<4 = s> ----> No
<4 = a> ----> e
<4 = l> ----> e
<4 = y> ----> No
<4 = p> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = y> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = p> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = w> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = d> AND <1 = s> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = d> AND <1 = f> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = d> AND <1 = y> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = l> AND <2 = y> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = l> AND <2 = w> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = l> AND <2 = c> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = l> AND <2 = n> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = g> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = h> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = k> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = r> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = n> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = o> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = b> ----> e
<4 = f> ----> No
<4 = c> ----> No
<4 = m> ----> No
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitris but this doesn't work on the nested subtrees

Comment: No sorted out the errors....using python 3 so had to sort that out but the dictionary is nested and your code is outputing the inner dictionaries as is , lemme post some of the output

Comment: How many levels deep is it nested? Based on the input you supplied the code is legit for python 2 and 3 (with the appropriate changes).

Comment: Have edited the question, I hadn't paused it correctly regarding the structure of the dict. Also new to stackoverflow so took a while to figure out the edit function. The nesting can be very deep depending on the dataset

Comment: Almost there, doesn't work when order of nesting is random e.g:  {4: {'s': 'No', 'a': 'e', 'p': 'No', 'c': 'No', 'l': 'e', 'f': 'No', 'm': 'No', 'n': {19: {'o': 'e', 'r': 'No', 'b': 'e', 'h': 'e', 'w': {21: {'p': 'e', 'w': 'e', 'd': {1: {'s': 'e', 'f': 'No', 'y': 'No'}}, 'g': 'e', 'l': {2: {'c': 'e', 'w': 'No', 'n': 'e', 'y': 'No'}}}}, 'k': 'e', 'n': 'e', 'y': 'e'}}, 'y': 'No'}}

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, I have updated my answer to include the output when running the script with the new dictionary you supplied. What exactly in the output isn't as you expected?

Comment: If your problem is that a rule is outputed with a numeric in the left side, then you must create your `dict` accordingly so all values of the right side of the rule are the nested correctly.

Comment: The rules starting <21 = d> AND <d = ......are the problem, they should all start at 4, the root

Comment: Okay, Gotcha, I'll look into it now.

Comment: Give it another look now, if you see something weird, hit me up. I've enjoyed this problem.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot man! My first time on stackoverflow and I have completely enjoyed it!!! Kudos

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem don't forget to up-vote and mark it as accepted for other users to know what worked.

Comment: Hate to be the bringer of bad news but there is slight problem in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th lines where it says AND <21 = d> AND <d = 1> AND <1 = y> should be  <21 = d>  AND <1 = y>.

Comment: Still a bit confused about the key-value pairs you want to use. I think the update matches the general pattern you want.

Comment: Finally, thanks again man. I still have to follow the code but for now I am just glad that the problem is solved. Thanks a lot man!!

Comment: Look into recursion a bit and you'll figure things out sooner or later. I'm glad after this back and forth commenting we at least got it done. As I previously mentioned, it is customary to [Accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped solve your problem. Either way, have a great day man!

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
# recursive build up the prefix for the current level
def format(rule, start=True, prefix=""):
    for (key, value) in rule.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, type({})):
            format(value, not start, ("{0}<{1} = " if start else "{0}{1}> AND ").format(prefix, key))
        else:
            print "{0}{1}> ----> {2}".format(prefix, key, value)
```

So, testing it on your larger set of rules/recursive dicts:

```
rules2 = {4: {'a': 'e',
     'c': 'No',
     'f': 'No',
     'l': 'e',
     'm': 'No',
     'n': {19: {'b': 'e',
                'h': 'e',
                'k': 'e',
                'n': 'e',
                'o': 'e',
                'r': 'No',
                'w': {21: {'d': {1: {'f': 'No', 's': 'e', 'y': 'No'}},
                           'g': 'e',
                           'l': {2: {'c': 'e', 'n': 'e', 'w': 'No', 'y': 'No'}},
                           'p': 'e',
                           'w': 'e'}},
                'y': 'e'}},
     'p': 'No',
     's': 'No',
     'y': 'No'}}

format(rules2)
```

Yields as output:

```
<4 = a> ----> e
<4 = p> ----> No
<4 = c> ----> No
<4 = f> ----> No
<4 = y> ----> No
<4 = s> ----> No
<4 = m> ----> No
<4 = l> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = b> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = p> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = w> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = d> AND <1 = y> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = d> AND <1 = s> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = d> AND <1 = f> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = g> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = l> AND <2 = y> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = l> AND <2 = c> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = l> AND <2 = w> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = w> AND <21 = l> AND <2 = n> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = y> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = h> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = k> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = r> ----> No
<4 = n> AND <19 = o> ----> e
<4 = n> AND <19 = n> ----> e
```